# dbQuery with condition and date_format()

Tags: entities

I have a request that should return a list of nodes that have a creation date <= 6 months. It works well with `$query->where()` but I want to use `$query->condition ()`.

Query with CONDITION:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->innerJoin('field_data_field_date_de_publication_news', 'fn', 'fn.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->innerJoin('field_data_body', 'fb', 'fb.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->fields('n', array('title', 'status', 'nid'));
$query->fields('fn', array('field_date_de_publication_news_value') );
$query->condition('fn.field_date_de_publication_news_value', 'MONTH(NOW())-6', '<='); 
$query->orderBy('fn.field_date_de_publication_news_value', 'DESC');    
$rows = $query->execute();
```

But if I replace CONDITION with WHERE it works:

```
$query->where(" MONTH(fn.field_date_de_publication_news_value) <= MONTH(NOW())-6" );
```

I also tried:

```
$query->fields('fn', array("DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(field_date_de_publication_news_value), '%m')") );
```

Comment: What is the question? So far, you simply stated some facts.

Answer (score 2):

`condition()` can only be used for simple expressions (`=`, `>`, `<`, `<>`, `BETWEEN`, `LIKE`, and a few others).

Using `where()` as you are already is the correct way to construct a more complex query.

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted as it explains why it isn't working.